# What is the term for/manufacturer of belay devices with a clip that holds the ATC onto the carabiner?

Tags: gear, rock-climbing, climbing, belaying

I broke my friend's ATC, and am trying to find a replacement, but I don't quite know what to look for.

It was a somewhat unique unit, at least among those I've seen; it was a standard "basket" ATC with a screw-lock carabiner, but it had a plastic clip that secured the cable from the ATC to the slotted side of the 'biner, presumably so there was no possibility of losing one or the other. The plastic wasn't structural/weight-bearing.

Either way, it broke, it's my fault, and I can't for the life of me figure out what to ask Google to find the term for such a device, or a manufacturer that sells them.

**Does anyone know what the term for a belay device with a plastic clip that secures the ATC to the carabiner is? More to the point: who manufactures them?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend?

Comment: Could you possibly provide us with a doodle of what it is you're trying to describe?

Comment: @ShemSeger that was going to be my next step :)

Comment: This, my friend, is why I always carry two belay devices.

Comment: "I broke my friend's ATC"  .... How?  It's a solid piece of metal.  :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you're referring to?

This is a **Petzl UNIREVERSO**:

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell you can only buy this as a complete system. You may have to contact a Petzl dealer to see if you can order the plastic connection piece individually.

Comment: Can someone explain what this achieves because I don't get it? the DMM stops cross loading, this doesn't seem to do a lot apart form hold your belay plate and carabiner together? It seems a bit gimmicky to me.

Comment: @Liam It holds your ATC away from your carabiner, which prevents it from locking when you're just feeding rope through it. It makes belaying a lot smoother.

Comment: Cool, ta for the info!

Comment: @Liam It essentially mimics the same function as a [spring on a belay plate](http://www.sportswarehouse.co.uk/products/Camp-Belay-Plate-with-Spring.html#.VQr_oOFTygU).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... could it be that you mean the DMM Belay master?

[image]

The main functions of the plastic clip are to ensure that the carabiner gate is screwed shut before it can be closed, and to prevent cross-loading of the carabiner.

Comment: Sounds like a belay master to me

Comment: I don't think so, the OP says the peice was on the ATC, not the biner.

Comment: @ShemSeger I also overlooked that at first sight. Seems the question is not about the Belay Master.